# ANOVA with Error term

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, experiment-design, nested-data, nested-models

I am looking for help to create a model for the following data:

I'd like to understand if the abundance of a certain microbial group (dependent continuous variable QUANTITY) found in soils is been affected by land-use, seasonality and their interaction. For each land-use (factor LAND-USE with 2 levels: forest and pasture), I have 3 different sites (factor SITE with 6 levels: F1, F2, and F3 for FOREST and P1, P2, and P3 for PASTURE). At each site, I collected soil samples in 5 points (factor POINT). Therefore, POINT is nested in SITE and SITE is nested in LAND-USE. In the end, I have 5 points per site and 15 per land-use, totaling 30 points in the study. However, each point was sampled twice (factor SEASON with 2 levels: DS and RS), during the dry and rainy seasons.

My dataframe looks like this:

```r
SEASON LAND-USE SITE POINT QUANTITY  
DS FOREST F1 F1_1 300.00  
DS FOREST F1 F1_2 330.00  
DS FOREST F1 F1_3 530.00  
DS FOREST F1 F1_4 670.00  
DS FOREST F1 F1_5 80.00  
DS FOREST F2 F2_1 600.00  
DS FOREST F2 F2_2 630.00  
DS FOREST F2 F2_3 780.00  
DS FOREST F2 F2_4 900.00  
DS FOREST F2 F2_5 1,000.00    
...  
RS PASTURE P3 P3_1 800.00    
RS PASTURE P3 P3_2 730.00  
RS PASTURE P3 P3_3 980.00  
RS PASTURE P3 P3_4 550.00  
RS PASTURE P3 P3_5 700.00
```

I am not interested in the site or point itself. I just need to know the effects of land-use and seasonality. However, I am not sure how to code site and point in the error term using AOV.

For example, what's the difference in the following codes? I know this is a very basic question, but even after reading a series of tutorials, I still do not understand which one I should choose in this case.

```r
aov(QUANTITY ~ Season * Land-use + Error(Site), archaea)  
aov(QUANTITY ~ Season * Land-use + Error(Point), archaea)  
aov(QUANTITY ~ Season * Land-use + Error(Site/Point), archaea)
```

I would appreciate any advice. If there is anything that I should clarify, please let me know!

Comment: The term 'use" is not clear to me. Further, what is the purpose of your study - season or use (or combined effect). Also, I can not understand "use " - is it use as pasture or intensity of pasture ? How do you quantify season for the analysis proposed.

Comment: Hi Subhash! My purpose is to understand the effect of season, land-use, and their interaction. I wrote "Use" in the model, but it's actually the variable "Land-use", with the levels forest and pasture. I am not studying the intensity of pasture itself, only both systems.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant with "How do you quantify season for the analysis proposed". Can you explain to me?

Comment: @Biomol: First, please add new information to the original Q as an edit, so all information is in one place. That will increase the probability of a good answer.  Second: For season, it is continuous or a factor? Which values can it take? 1,2,...,12 for month, say, or "spring", summer", ... ? Same for other variables.

Comment: Thank you @kjetilbhalvorsen. I made all the alterations in the original text. About season, it's a factor with two levels (DS and RS). All other independent variables are factors too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a split-plot design, see for instance [Split Plot Design? lmer analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148673/split-plot-design-lmer-analysis)  or  [Can I test the effect of Block in a split plot design in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5768/can-i-test-the-effect-of-block-in-a-split-plot-design-in-r?rq=1).  The modern way to analyze this in `R` is to use the package `lme4`, although if your design is perfectly balanced `aov` might work.

Since you have `Point` nested within `Site`, the correct specification should be the analog of your third one:

```r
lme4::lmer(QUANTITY ~ Season * Land-use + (1 | Site/Point), 
           data=archaea)
```

where the term `(1 | Site/Point)` means a random constant for each Site, and for Point within Site.  This will give correct estimates also in the case of unbalanced data, something `aov` will not.

If you will post your data I will have a look.